# What is the best way of getting volume button presses programatically?

Tags: c, linux, gtk

I am writing a GTK3 app that needs to intercept volume button presses. The normal "key-press-event" signal works for all other keys, but does not show volume keys. I've managed to do this before by reading an input_event struct from /dev/input/whatever, but it was very janky and cumbersome, especially when there were multiple input devices.

Is there a better way to do this? Or is there a clean way to implement the input_event method?

Comment: What software handles your volume buttons at the moment? Maybe look at how it works

Comment: Working hypothesis 0: volume button keys are normally assigned as hotkeys. In X11 parlance, they are grabbed, presumably by GNOME (or your WM/desktop-manager/Windows-GUI-emulator or whatever it is called these days), so your program won't receive those. To confirm, open your hotkey manager (whatever it is), find volume keys, unassign them, and try running your application again.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. That was the issue. I'm writing the app for a  minimal openbox based distro, so it ended up being a non-issue. Thanks!